# How to adjust NVIDIA GPU fan speed on a headless node?

Tags: nvidia, gpu, headless, fan

How is it possible to control the fan speed of multiple consumer NVIDIA GPUs such as Titan and 1080 Ti on a headless node running Linux?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following is a simple method that does not require scripting, connecting fake monitors, or fiddling and can be executed over SSH to control multiple NVIDIA GPUs' fans. It has been tested on Arch Linux.

### Create xorg.conf

`sudo nvidia-xconfig --allow-empty-initial-configuration --enable-all-gpus --cool-bits=7`

This will create an `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` with an entry for each GPU, similar to the manual method.

**Note:** Some distributions (Fedora, CentOS, Manjaro) have additional config files (eg in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` or `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/`), which override `xorg.conf` and set `AllowNVIDIAGPUScreens`. This option is not compatible with this guide. The extra config files should be modified or deleted. The X11 log file shows which config files have been loaded.

### Alternative: Create xorg.conf manually

#### Identify your cards' PCI IDs:

`nvidia-xconfig --query-gpu-info`

Find the `PCI BusID` fields. Note that these are not the same as the bus IDs reported in the kernel.

Alternatively, do `sudo startx`, open `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` (or whatever location startX lists in its output under the line "Log file:"), and look for the line `NVIDIA(0): Valid display device(s) on GPU-<GPU number> at PCI:<PCI ID>`.

#### Edit `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`

Here is an example of `xorg.conf` for a three-GPU machine:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier "dual"
        Screen 0 "Screen0"
        Screen 1 "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
        Screen 1 "Screen2" RightOf "Screen1"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BusID          "PCI:5:0:0"
    Option         "Coolbits"       "7"
    Option         "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BusID          "PCI:6:0:0"
    Option         "Coolbits"       "7"
    Option         "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device2"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BusID          "PCI:9:0:0"
    Option         "Coolbits"       "7"
    Option         "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier     "Screen0"
        Device         "Device0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier     "Screen1"
        Device         "Device1"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier     "Screen2"
        Device         "Device2"
EndSection
```

The `BusID` must match the bus IDs we identified in the previous step. The option `AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration` allows X to start even if no monitor is connected. The option `Coolbits` allows fans to be controlled. It can also allow overclocking.

**Note:** Some distributions (Fedora, CentOS, Manjaro) have additional config files (eg in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` or `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/`), which override `xorg.conf` and set `AllowNVIDIAGPUScreens`. This option is not compatible with this guide. The extra config files should be modified or deleted. The X11 log file shows which config files have been loaded.

### Edit `/root/.xinitrc`

```
nvidia-settings -q fans
nvidia-settings -a [gpu:0]/GPUFanControlState=1 -a [fan:0]/GPUTargetFanSpeed=75
nvidia-settings -a [gpu:1]/GPUFanControlState=1 -a [fan:1]/GPUTargetFanSpeed=75
nvidia-settings -a [gpu:2]/GPUFanControlState=1 -a [fan:2]/GPUTargetFanSpeed=75
```

I use .xinitrc to execute nvidia-settings for convenience, although there's probably other ways. The first line will print out every GPU fan in the system. Here, I set the fans to 75%.

### Launch X

```
sudo startx -- :0
```

You can execute this command from SSH. The output will be:

```
Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat May 27 02:22:08 2017
(==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"

  Attribute 'GPUFanControlState' (pushistik:0[gpu:0]) assigned value 1.

  Attribute 'GPUTargetFanSpeed' (pushistik:0[fan:0]) assigned value 75.


  Attribute 'GPUFanControlState' (pushistik:0[gpu:1]) assigned value 1.

  Attribute 'GPUTargetFanSpeed' (pushistik:0[fan:1]) assigned value 75.


  Attribute 'GPUFanControlState' (pushistik:0[gpu:2]) assigned value 1.

  Attribute 'GPUTargetFanSpeed' (pushistik:0[fan:2]) assigned value 75.
```

### Monitor temperatures and clock speeds

`nvidia-smi` and `nvtop` can be used to observe temperatures and power draw. Lower temperatures will allow the card to clock higher and increase its power draw. You can use `sudo nvidia-smi -pl 150` to limit power draw and keep the cards cool, or use `sudo nvidia-smi -pl 300` to let them overclock. My 1080 Ti runs at 1480 MHz if given 150W, and over 1800 MHz if given 300W, but this depends on the workload. You can monitor their clock speed with `nvidia-smi -q` or more specifically, `watch 'nvidia-smi -q | grep -E "Utilization|  Graphics|Power Draw"'`

#### Returning to automatic fan management.

Reboot. I haven't found another way to make the fans automatic.

Comment: Are you able to individually control fans on each GPU this way? I've seen that EVGA 1080 Ti cards using this method only change the #1 ( of 3 fans ). Any recommendations for Linux-friendly brands that don't use non-standard Methods of configuration (such as EVGA does)?

Comment: @ehiller I only have Founder's Edition cards which have a single blower-style fan. Such a cooler works better when multiple cards are in a system. What does `nvidia-settings -q fans` show? (You can execute it inside .xinitrc) Maybe you can adjust all the fans if you address them correctly.

Comment: When starting X server, I get `Fatal server error: (EE) no screens found(EE) ` Any ideas?

Comment: @Arin Not sure, but is `AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration` properly set for the correct PCI ID in xorg.conf? That file can be tricky.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky Yup. Figured it out, by the way. First I went on the graphical environment. Then, I ran `env > env.txt`, and whenever i would try to adjust it, I would run the command with the environmental variables stored in `env.txt`. Works perfectly. Thanks again!

Comment: @Arin what do you think were the relevant environment variables?

Comment: There'a a tool provided by NVIDIA to generate the xorg.conf file automatically and it works pretty great: `nvidia-xconfig --allow-empty-initial-configuration --enable-all-gpus --cool-bits=28 --separate-x-screens`

Comment: Also, if you want to know the devices PCI ID they are available as a kernal log message: `dmesg | grep nvidia-modeset` 

Example output:

```[   16.616666] nvidia-modeset: Allocated GPU:0 (GPU-72750a8b-77b2-1daf-99bd-5113e845eddf) @ PCI:0000:01:00.0```

Comment: @HubertPerron The PCI IDs in dmesg are the same ones as in `lspci` and do NOT correspond to the ones used by X on my Threadripper platform.

Comment: @HubertPerron Why do you add option `--separate-x-screens`? It seems to create a lot of unnecessary `Screen` sections. Do you have information on how to overclock and over/undervolt the GPU from the command line?

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky on my machines the `cool-bits` option was ignored on GPUs that weren't associated to their own `x-screen` and overclocking was disabled. Maybe this isn't necessary but it fixed my problem with the `cool-bits` being ignored.

Comment: Afaik you can't undervolt NVIDIA GPUs without messing with custom BIOS. Instead i'm setting a software power limit value in watt: `nvidia-smi -pl 120`. This will limit power consumption of every GPU to 120W.

You can also overclock/underclock core and mem using `nvidia-smi` or `nvidia-settings`.

There's overclocking example in the `nvidia-smi` doc here: https://devblogs.nvidia.com/increase-performance-gpu-boost-k80-autoboost

If you have `nvidia-settings` installed you can apply a clock offset without having to use specific clock: `nvidia-settings -a [gpu]/GPUGraphicsClockOffset[3]=100`

Answer (score 5):

[I've written a pip-installable Python script to do something similar to @AlexsandrDubinsky's suggestion](https://github.com/andyljones/coolgpus).

> When you run fans.py, it sets up a temporary X server for each GPU with a fake display attached. Then, it loops over the GPUs every few seconds and sets the fan speed according to their temperature. When the script dies, it returns control of the fans to the drivers and cleans up the X servers.

Comment: Thanks! Something which I tried to figure out but couldn't is how to do this whole thing inside Docker and avoid installing X server. Have you tried this?

Comment: Haven't tried it I'm afraid, and I can't think of a way to do it without X server being accessible. Would have to set the fan speed by another way than `nvidia-settings`

Comment: Well, the nvidia driver is accessible within containers and can be used for running eg CUDA. I think it should be possible to launch X server and have it talk to the nvidia driver, but I haven't had luck so far.

Comment: Have you by any chance heard about any new features for this? With the current heat I can only use the two outer GPUs of my 4 Titan XP setup for CUDA computations, and even then they clock down due to high heat. I was hoping that I could manually control the inner two GPU's fan speed to help cooling the outer two, but it seems a hassle to set up? Edit: Also working in a docker instance on our compute cluster.

Comment: If I'm understanding you right then that's too specialised to be something I'd add to coolgpus itself, but it's a simple script and you should be able to fork it and adapt it to your purposes. Open an issue if you get stuck. NB: I'd be surprised if you could adjust the fan settings from within a Docker container though, usually you need sudo.

Answer (score 2):

Based on answers to this question and similar StackExchange questions, I wrote a shell script that will set the fan speed to `100` (or whatever value you want) to *all* of your fans on *all* of your GPUs on a machine.

This script assumes your machine has X11 installed, but that you aren't using it to serve a GUI to a user.

**/bin/set-gpu-fan-speed.sh**:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
set -Eeuxo pipefail

# Kill any existing X servers.
killall Xorg || true
sleep 5

# Create a NVIDIA-friendly Xorg config.
nvidia-xconfig -a --cool-bits=28 --allow-empty-initial-configuration --enable-all-gpus

# Start a new X server for nvidia-settings to use.
export XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
export DISPLAY=:0
startx -- $DISPLAY &
sleep 5

# Determine the number of GPUs and fans on this machine.
NUM_GPUS=$(nvidia-settings -q gpus | grep -c 'gpu:')
NUM_FANS=$(nvidia-settings -q fans | grep -c 'fan:')

# For each GPU, enable fan control.
for ((i=0; i < NUM_GPUS; i++))
do
    nvidia-settings --verbose=all -a "[gpu:$i]/GPUFanControlState=1"
done

# For each fan, set fan speed to 100%.
for ((i=0; i < NUM_FANS; i++))
do
    nvidia-settings --verbose=all -a "[fan:$i]/GPUTargetFanSpeed=100"
done

# Kill the X server that we started.
killall Xorg || true
```

These fan speed changes do not persist across reboots, so I've written a systemd unit file to run the above script on every boot.

**/etc/systemd/system/set-gpu-fan-speed.service**:

```
[Unit]
Description="Sets the GPU fan speed"

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=root
ExecStart=/bin/set-gpu-fan-speed.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After creating the above file, run the following commands as root to enable the script running on reboot.

```
systemctl enable set-gpu-fan-speed.service
systemctl start set-gpu-fan-speed.service
```

Comment: what changes would i need to make if I am running on a laptop?

Comment: @techcheese: I am not sure. But if you're using your laptop's graphical display like a normal person, I guess you could skip the parts of my script that involve killing or starting Xorg.